# Find out where required permission comes from

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I just realized that my Mono for Android app requires the INTERNET permission although I haven't set it in my Mono Develop project settings. I guess it comes from one of the libraries which are referenced by my project by means of the [UsesPermission] attribute
(http://docs.xamarin.com/android/releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_For_Android_4.0.0).

However, at first glance I cannot find any such attribute at the referenced libraries through the Mono Develop project explorer. Is there any easy way to find out what causes the permission to be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read in a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5792869/292233 that Mono for Android adds the INTERNET permission to all Debug builds to enable debugging. In Release, it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the standard Mono for Android template the following lines are present:

```
// Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
```

This can also be the culprit of adding extra permissions to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can add them is via the Project file. Right click on the project, select Properties. Then clicking on the Android Manifest tab. (If your project doesn't already have a `AndroidManifest.xml` file you can click on the "Add AndroidManifest.XML" button). You will see a scrollable list of all the possible permissions in Android. Click off the ones your application should be requesting.

You can refer to [this document on Xamarin's website](http://docs.xamarin.com/node/18768) for some screenshots on the the whole process.

Comment: that was not the question: I looked in this list and didn't check the Internet permission, but it was still requested by my app. So I wanted to know where the permission could come from "although I haven't set it in my Mono Develop project settings"